# Math in lwarp (via controlled expansion?)

Tags: expansion, lwarp

Here is the issue I am thinking about, and some possible approaches. When writing a latex/html document using lwarp, the math code is left embedded directly into the resulting HTML file and left up to mathjax to interpret.

If there are non-standard macros in there, they will not be expanded by latex, and mathjax will not know what to do with them -- (1) below. The standard approach is to just give mathjax the macro definitions (`\CustomizeMathJax` below). Mathjax has macros for this purpose and I don't disagree.

However, sometimes a macro is more complex than this; for instance, in a recent application I needed a macro which added an argument to a fixed offset. This was simple in tex; in mathjax I needed to reimplement the macro in JS (and now I will need to reimplement it when I switch the MathJax 3.)

This feels like a perfect place for some kind of controlled expansion. For instance, consider the example below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}

\newcommand\xyz{x}
\newcommand\bfxyz{\mathbf{x}}

% `Standard' solution:
%\CustomizeMathJax{\newcommand\xyz{x}} 
%\CustomizeMathJax{\newcommand\bfxyz{\mathbf{x}}}

\begin{document}

\[ (1) \quad a + b = \xyz,\bfxyz . \]

\edef\mymath{%
\noexpand\[ (2) \noexpand\quad a + b = \xyz. \noexpand\]
}
\mymath

\edef\mymath{%
\noexpand\[ (3) \noexpand\quad a + b = \expandonce\bfxyz. \noexpand\]
}
\mymath

\end{document}
```

[image: (1) a + x = (red text) \xyz, \bfxyz; (2) a + b = x; (3) a + b = (bold) x]

Using edefs and expanding only certain macros, I can get tex to do the expansion and not have to worry about what mathjax sees.

However, this is obviously not really a solution: I had to add `\noexpand` in front of a lot things related to math mode. I also had to be pretty careful about how many times things were expanded, either adding `\expandonce` as in (3) or rewriting the macro definition as `\newcommand\bfxyz{\noexpand\mathbf{x}}`, say.

It feels like what I really want to do is to expand *only* the macros in some list (e.g., \xyz,\bfxyz), and do that until nothing in the list remains. But maybe there is another approach that I don't know about -- possibly something using `\protected@edef`?

So, is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `\protected@edef` does what you need here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mathjax]{lwarp}

\newcommand\xyz{x}
\newcommand\bfxyz{\mathbf{x}}

% `Standard' solution:
%\CustomizeMathJax{\newcommand\xyz{x}} 
%\CustomizeMathJax{\newcommand\bfxyz{\mathbf{x}}}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\[ (1) \quad a + b = \xyz,\bfxyz . \]

\protected@edef\mymath{%
\[ (2) \quad a + b = \xyz.\]
}
\show\mymath
\mymath

\protected@edef\mymath{%
\[ (3) \quad a + b = \bfxyz. \]
}
\show\mymath
\mymath

\end{document}
```

Produces this log

```
> \mymath=macro:
->\protect \[ (2) \hskip 1em\relax a + b = x.\protect \] .
l.19 \show\mymath

? 
> \mymath=macro:
->\protect \[ (3) \hskip 1em\relax a + b = \protect \mathbf  {x}. \protect \] .
l.25 \show\mymath
```

If there are any standard commands that do expand in the protected@edef you could redeclare then as robust using `\MakeRobust\zzz`  so thre expansion is stopped.

For examle I assumed above it is OK for `\quad` to expand but if you want to hold it as `\quad` add

```
\MakeRobust\quad
```

to the preamble then the log shows

```
> \mymath=macro:
->\protect \[ (2) \protect \quad  a + b = x.\protect \] .
l.21 \show\mymath

? 
> \mymath=macro:
->\protect \[ (3) \protect \quad  a + b = \protect \mathbf  {x}. \protect \] .
l.27 \show\mymath
```

Comment: I think you're right. Actually, your version does not compile under lwarp, but replacing `\[ ... \]` with `\[ ... \noexpand\]` does work. (For some reason, `\]` is undefined when lwarp does the html run.) Do you think that this approach is robust, in the sense that there aren't many/any fragile commands that would wreak havoc if this was applied generally? This is the purpose of the fragile/robust distinction, right?

Comment: @AlexWatson there are not that many fragile commands (and the next version of latex that you can already test as `pdflatex-dev` in texlive at least) will have far fewer fragile commands. In any case any command that dies in protected@edef will definitely die in \edef so it is certainly a step in the right direction compared to the version in the question... you might want to take up the `\[` behaviour with the lwarp maintainer, it ought not to break, I think.

Comment: Thank you. I do think this is a good working solution, and I'll write to the maintainer (if he isn't watching the tag.)